# SQL scoped Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, auto-increment

I have a database table which contains jobs for various companies. Each job has a foreign key column of `company_id` which assigns the job to a company.

We are trying to scope the job to a company, which means that the first job of a new company should always have an ID of 1.

The first solution which comes to mind is adding a new column to the jobs table and letting the server assign those IDs by fetching the last job of that company and incrementing the ID by 1 but it seems like a lot of logic to build by keeping in mind deleted jobs and if the company has not added any previous jobs.

My question is, is there an existing database design solution that would be able to solve this issue perhaps on the database side or is there a better solution from the server side to set this up?

Comment: In general, you would have to do this using a trigger.

Comment: Thank you. Do I assume correct that when a new record is added I would auto-increment the new ID column based on the last record for the given organisation?

Comment: . . Yes.  You might use the same trigger to keep the most recent value available in another table, so you don't need to search for it each time.